# Historical proof of Leschetz Hyperplane Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, fibration

I browse in Phillip Griffiths' [Slides](https://www.ias.edu/sites/default/files/video/IASslides.pdf)
on historical development of
Hodge-theory and these include a sketch of the original approach
with Lefschetz used to study complex surfaces in his famous
[hypersurface theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_hyperplane_theorem).

The part where I need some clarifications in presented on pages
22-**24**.

The idea was to study embedded complex surfaces $$ S = \{f(x,y,z)=0 \} \subset \mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}  $$

($y \in \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{P}^1$ if we compactify $S$)
by inductive methods on their dimension and so consideringing the fibers

$$  C_y = \{f(x,y,z)=0, y = \text{ constant } \}   $$

of the projection map to first coordinate which in a modern framework corresponds
to map $F:\overline{S} \to \mathbb{P}^1$ which is given by
Lefschetz fibration which arise as blow up along the base locus of the pencil. The next argument on slide 24 (of see below for the picture) I not understand.

Historically Lefschetz' idea was to introduce slits like below
in the base space $\mathbb{P}^1$ where $y_1,..., y_N$ correspond to points
having *singular* fiber $C_{y_i}$ and $C_{y_0}$ is a fixed smooth
reference curve.

The next step is confusing. It says that since the complement
of the above configuration $R:= \bigcup_{i=0}^N \overline{y_0 y_i}$
is contractible in sphere
$\mathbb{P}^1 \cong S^2$, so
the whole surface retracts onto the part lying over the slits in the complex
plane. Here the important slide:

[image]

Why? The last sentence on the right in the image doesn't make any sense. The existence of such retraction fails already in the base space,
since there is no retraction of whole $S^2$ onto $R$, so
so why should exist a 'lifted' retraction of $S$ into
$F^{-1}(R)$.

Maybe I misunderstand to idea. Does anybody see what is here meant? I think that this slides are going to elaborate the gaps of the unclear sketch of Lefschetz original proof [from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_hyperplane_theorem#Lefschetz%27s_proof) , but this retraction statement confuses me.

Comment: There is a nice exposition of Lefschetz's proof from a more modern point of view by Klaus Lamotke (Topology 20 (1981) 15-41.) I'm not sure if it directly addresses your questions but it is rather detailed and so perhaps it would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. The strategy in §5 (34) of this paper
is quite similar. Essentially one important step there exploits
that if we *remove* the point $\infty$ at infinity from $\mathbb{P}^1 \cong S^2$
then of couse $\mathbb{P}^1 - \infty$ retracts to 
$R:= \bigcup_{i=0}^N \overline{y_0 y_i}$
and the proof of this paper shows that the restricted lifts admit
also such retraction. 

Maybe implicitely Griffiths assumed in the image above the infinity
point also to be already removed, otherwise the second sentence 
below the graph in the image doesn't make any sense.